# Which is the best ROS2 distribution for Jetson NX for develop object detection?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am considering to use ROS2 to develop application Detect object on Jetson NX.
Could someone have make some compare between ROS2 distribution?
Which ROS2 distribution is the best compatible to work on Jetson NX?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385248/which-is-the-best-ros2-distribution-for-jetson-nx-for-develop-object-detection?/) by [ROS_LOVER](https://answers.ros.org/users/82451/ros_lover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @ROS_LOVER,

> Which ROS2 distribution is the best compatible to work on Jetson NX?

I think currently it's foxy that can be sustainable to your requirement.

For object detection, you need a darknet_ros I think it is available for foxy.

https://index.ros.org/r/darknet_ros/#galactic

https://index.ros.org/r/darknet_ros/#foxy

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_LOVER](https://answers.ros.org/users/82451/ros_lover/) on 2021-08-27**:
Hi @Ranjit Kathiriya,
Thank you for your answer.

I have found that Jetson NX SDK Jetpack only support to ubuntu 18.04 .
So I have to run new ROS2 version through Docker image create by Nvidia Developer.
Do you have any experience on this situation ?
If I want to choose some older ROS2 Distribution : Eloquent, Dashing , Crystal support directly Ubuntu 18.04?
Do you have any experience about using these distribution ?

Thanks

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-27**:
Have a look at this link.

https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installROS2

**Comment by [ROS_LOVER](https://answers.ros.org/users/82451/ros_lover/) on 2021-08-27**:
Thank for your advice. Have you try using this source yet?
Is there any trouble?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-30**:
I think you have to try the hit-and-run approach over here. No! sorry I have not tried myself.